# Is the "firebase login:ci" token tied to a specific project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

When I use `firebase login:ci` to get a token, is that tied to the project that is selected with `firebase use` or is it a token that will work with any/all of my projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sign-in token is associated with a user. It should grant access to all projects of the signed-in user.